# Prove: $\|\lambda v\| = |\lambda| \cdot \|v\| $

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Prove: $\|\lambda v\| = |\lambda| \cdot \|v\| $, for a vector space $V$ with an inner product and $\lambda \in F$,

How do we prove this?

I understand the geometric meaning is that if you multiply a vector by a scalar then you make it length greater by that scalar times, and even if you multiply by a minus-signed scalar then you actually lengthen it by the same $|\lambda|$ but to the other direction. But how do we algebraically prove this?

Comment: What is your definition of "inner product"?

Comment: $< \cdot , \cdot >$. Let's take the standard one for example.

Comment: You have the definition of the norm, $\lVert x\rVert = \sqrt{\langle x \mid x \rangle}$ presumably. Now, what can you say about $\langle \lambda x \mid \lambda x\rangle$?

Comment: What? Your question was for *any* space with an inner product. Are you changing that to one specific inner product?

Comment: $<\lambda x , \lambda x> = \lambda <x, \lambda x> = \lambda \lambda^{-} <x,x>$?

Comment: If $dim V<+\infty$ we have $v=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\Rightarrow k.v=(kx_1,kx_2,...,kx_n)\\ ||kv||=\sqrt{<kv.kv>}$.

Comment: An inner product necessarily has linearity in the first slot and conjugate linearity in the second slot, so the specific inner product (and even the domain) is irrelevant.

Comment: @Orangutango: Well, it has linearity in one slot and conjugate linearity in the other. Which is the first one is a matter of convention (in physics, it's always the first slot that gets the conjugation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes nearly immediately from the definitions.

Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be the inner product, which is linear in the first slot and
conjugate linear in the second slot. 
Then 
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda v\| &= \sqrt{ \langle \lambda v , \lambda v\rangle}\\
&= \sqrt{\lambda \cdot \langle v, \lambda v\rangle }\\
&= \sqrt{\lambda \cdot \overline{\lambda}  \cdot \langle v,v\rangle}\\
&= \sqrt{ |\lambda|^2 \cdot \langle v,v\rangle}\\
&= |\lambda| \cdot \sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}\\
&= |\lambda|\cdot \|v\|
\end{align*}

Comment: In $\mathbb C$, $\lambda \cdot \bar{\lambda}$ is $\lambda^2$ too?

Comment: @TheNotMe Sorry was in the real valued case changed it

Comment: Didn't you change the order? I thought that $<\lambda v, \lambda v> = \lambda <v, \lambda v> = \lambda \bar{\lambda} <v,v>$. I mean, the scalar on the right goes as conjugate and on the left goes normally. No?

Comment: @TheNotMe I assumed to take the first slot to be semilinear (you conjugate it  here ) and in the second linear. Please note, that this is often defined the other way around. Shall I change it?

Comment: Yes please, and thank you for the nice effort!

Comment: @TheNotMe Changed it :)